# Little MVC logic: where to put data-formatting function?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have places to list, both on homepage, and as a result of searching.

**MODEL:**

```
SELECT fields FROM blablabla
```

so result:

```
[[id,name],[id,name],[id,name]]
```

Since places can have own page, I have to convert. It cant be done in model, so:

**CONTROLLER:**

Iterate through hits and doing converts by ID and NAME.

[[id,name,seo_name],[id,name,seo_name],[id,name,seo_name]]

*[1, 'place1'] -> [1, 'place1', '1_place1']*

**VIEW:**

just show it.

But this time, I have to do it again on a "search" page. I cant copy-paste converting code from the previous controller, so I need to create this function, but where to put?

Comment: I’m having difficulty understanding what you’re asking. Exactly *what* data are you wanting to format?

Comment: edited. I need to add a SEO name

Comment: Is there any particular reason why your database results are not mapped into domain objects?

Comment: i would just add a helper class outside of the controller wich builds up the seo name if you have to reuse the code multiple times unless you have your controller inherit from a controller layout where you could add it.

Comment: Data formatting is part of presentation logic. Guess where that goes?

Answer (score 1):

As Jack says in the comments, you should have classes representing rows in your database table. So if you have a `pages` table with an `id`, `title` and `seo_title` columns, then you should have a class that represents that in your application:

```
<?php
class Page
{
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $seo_title;
}
```

In terms of creating an SEO-friendly title, you would normally have a “before save” callback or setter method in your `Page` model that runs a function on the `title` property, lower-casing it, removing spaces and punctuation etc. This could just be a helper class.

If you had a slug helper (SEO-friendly titles are also known as slugs) then you can just call it in your setter method:

```
<?php
class Page
{
    public $title;
    public $slug;

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->slug = SlugHelper::createSlug($title);
    }
}
```

And then call your setter method to create your slug when you set your page’s title:

```
$page = new Page();
$page->setTitle('My Page');

print $page->title; // My Page
print $page->slug; // would be something like 'my-page'
```

And then you can save your page model to the database knowing it will have an SEO-friendly title as well.